# How to pass additional parameters to python callback?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following sample block of code, where i'm trying to translate text from one language to another. I need to be able to pass in an additional argument that represents which target language i want to translate into.

How do i add another argument to the list of arguments from the callback in `boltons.iterutils.remap`?

I thought maybe using the `**kwargs` in the `remap` call would work, but it doesn't. It raises a TypeError:

```
raise TypeError('unexpected keyword arguments: %r' % kwargs.keys())
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import json
from boltons.iterutils import remap

def visit(path, key, value, lang='es'):
    if value is None or value == '' or not isinstance(value, str):
        return key, value
    return key, '{}:{}'.format(lang, value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_dict = { 'a': 'This is text', 'b': { 'c': 'This is more text', 'd': 'Another string' }, 'e': [ 'String A', 'String B', 'String C' ], 'f': 13, 'g': True, 'h': 34.4}
    print(remap(test_dict, visit=visit, lang='ru'))
```

Comment: Does this `boltons.iterutils.remap` thing have additional parameters to pass to the callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `boltons.iterutils.remap` doesn't pass additional keyword parameters to its callback - and one really wouldn't expect it to. So, you can't call `visit` directly. You can, however, call a different function that fills in the value for you. This is a good use-case for `lambda`.

```
import json
from boltons.iterutils import remap

def visit(path, key, value, lang='es'):
    if value is None or value == '' or not isinstance(value, str):
        return key, value
    return key, '{}:{}'.format(lang, value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_dict = { 'a': 'This is text', 'b': { 'c': 'This is more text', 'd': 'Another string' }, 'e': [ 'String A', 'String B', 'String C' ], 'f': 13, 'g': True, 'h': 34.4}
    print(remap(test_dict, visit=lambda key, value: visit(key, value, lang='ru')))
```

Comment: Great idea. I'm still learning when to apply lambda functions, so it didn't occur to me.

Comment: You could do the same thing wtih a regular function `def foo(key, value): return visit(key, value, lang='ru')` - this is just one of those times when a `lambda` fits and you don't have to think of a function name.